Need to merge 2 dictionaries in Ansible with the same key
I have 2 dictionaries in an Ansible playbook (ints & interfaces) which share the same key (interface name) and I'd like to merge them into one dictionary.
The ints dictionary have this structure:
"ints": {
        "GigabitEthernet 1/1": {
            "bandwidth": 1000,
            "description": null,
            "duplex": "full",
            "ipv4": null,
            "lineprotocol": "up",
            "macaddress": "8c:47:be:64:8a:82",
            "mediatype": null,
            "mtu": 1554,
            "operstatus": "up",
            "type": "DellEth"
        }

and the interfaces has this structure:
 "interfaces": {
        "GigabitEthernet 1/1": {
            "lag": "",
            "mode": "Tagged",
            "tagged": [
                "1007"
            ],
            "untagged": "1641"
        }

I'm trying to merge them doing this:
 - name: Combine dictionaries
      set_fact:
        merged_dict: "{{ ints | combine(interfaces) }}"

    - debug:
        var: merged_dict

With the hope of getting this:
 "merged_dict": {
       "GigabitEthernet 1/1": {
             "bandwidth": 1000,
            "description": null,
            "duplex": "full",
            "ipv4": null,
            "lineprotocol": "up",
            "macaddress": "8c:47:be:64:8a:82",
            "mediatype": null,
            "mtu": 1554,
            "operstatus": "up",
            "type": "DellEth"
            "lag": "",
            "mode": "Tagged",
            "tagged": [
                "1007"
            ],
            "untagged": "1641"
        }

But instead I'm only getting this:
"merged_dict": {
       "GigabitEthernet 1/1": {
            "lag": "",
            "mode": "Tagged",
            "tagged": [
                "1007"
            ],
            "untagged": "1641"
        }

Can someone with more experience point me to what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much and have a great day

Try with recursive=true. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/combine_filter.html#keyword-parameters
